# How to achieve record-based access control in odoo 14?

Tags: odoo, crud, access-rights, odoo-14, record-rules

We have a requirement to add multiple user roles to an object in odoo.

Current requirement is with Partner Model. Odoo Partner Record can have multiple users assigned from organization with different roles. Based on the role individual can Create, Edit, Read or Delete the record.

For example:

Top Company is a record in odoo partner which has 3 users assigned.

1. User 1 (Whos is Driver): Can Read this record. Cannot Edit or Delete
2. User 2 (Who is Sales Person): Can Read this record. Can Edit. Cannot Delete
3. User 3 (Who is Account Executive): Can Read this record. Can Edit. Can Delete

Can someone please guide how to achieve this in odoo 14 community edition.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
KK